# Search in Array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, find, mongodb-query

I have a collection "room_user" with these document -

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("524d1ae07847c05671a2965c"),
    "room_name" : "room1",
    "members" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user2"
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("524d1aec7847c05671a2965d"),
    "room_name" : "room2",
    "members" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user2", 
        "user3"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("524d1af27847c05671a2965e"),
    "room_name" : "room3",
    "members" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user2", 
        "user4"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("524d1b387847c05671a2965f"),
    "room_name" : "room4",
    "members" : [ 
        "user1", 
        "user5"
    ]
}
```

Now I want to search/get the name of room ("room_name") where ONLY user1 and user2 are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the query you are looking for:

```
db.room_user.find(
  { "$and": 
    [ 
      { "members": { "$all": [ "user2", "user1" ] } } ,
      { "members": { "$size": 2 } } 
    ]
  },
  { "room_name": 1 }
)
```

1. The first part of the query matches the members array that contains all of the desired elements. In addition it will only match an array with a size of 2.
2. The second part is the projection where we are only returning the `room_name` attribute. Note that you'll also get the `_id` attribute unless you specifically state that you don't want it.

---

### Index considerations:

The documentation of the `$all` operator has this to say regarding the use of indexes when using this operator (emphasis added):

> Note In most cases, MongoDB does not treat arrays as sets. This
>   operator provides a notable exception to this approach. **In the current
>   release queries that use the `$all` operator must scan all the documents
>   that match the first element in the query array. As a result, even
>   with an index to support the query, the operation may be long running,
>   particularly when the first element in the array is not very
>   selective.**

Comment: I have to search/get "room_name" so can't provide that in query. I tried this query without room_name and its not working :(

Comment: The room name is not in the query. It is in the projection. There is a difference. The protection defines what fields you want Mongo to return

Comment: ah..yes.. but this query is not working? have you tried this?

Comment: The query is most likely not working because object comparison is order sensitive.

Comment: @Sammaye order sensitive? :( is there any way we can search in any order? or I have to modify my document structure?

Comment: @sau - I believe that my edits should give you what you are looking for. The ordering of the users doesn't matter now as we are searching for an array containing all of the supplied elements and with the same length.

Comment: @Lix I don't recommend to use **$all** operator since it's a *slow op that doesn't use indexes*. Please check out the note in this link: [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/#op._S_all]

Comment: @ora - good observation! Indeed with regard to performance it would be wise to take this into consideration. That being said - the query will still work.

Comment: @sau - I recommend running some tests on your actual dataset. You can also try swapping `$all` with `$in` and running `explain()` on the cursor to see what indexes are being used.

Comment: @Lix sorry for disturbance.. Actually I am learning mongo db and reading a book currently... I get to know this "An Array can monstly be treated as though each element is the value of the overall key" .. this way we can match value with array key name.. so I wrote this query - `db.room_user.find({ "$and":[{"members":"user1"},{"members":"user2"}]})` this is working and also in any order.. now I want to understand what is better? "$all" or using this query?